# How to check if array type is cumulative sum type or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, cumulative-sum

as I mentioned in the title, I have multiple arrays which include some data. Some of the arrays have cumulative numbers, the others have randomized datas. What I am trying to do is, 
Logic: `if an array is not cumulative, then make it cumulative.`

```
//Randomized arrays are
arrays= [[
  '0.029', '0.029', '0.030', '0.030', '0.031', '0.031',
  '0.032', '0.032', '0.033', '0.034', '0.034', '0.034',
  '0.039', '0.039', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.002', '0.003', '0.003', '0.004', '0.004',
  '0.005', '0.006', '0.006', '0.007', '0.007', '0.008',
  '0.011', '0.012', '0.012', '0.013', '0.014', '0.014',
  '0.015', '0.015', '0.016', '0.017'
],
[
  '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002',
  '0.003', '0.003', '0.003', '0.003',
  '0.003', '0.004', '0.004', '0.004',
  '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.001', '0.001', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.001', '0.001', '0.002',
  '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002',
  '0.003', '0.003', '0.003'
],
// Cumulative array
[
  '0.002', '0.004', '0.006', '0.008',
  '0.011', '0.014', '0.017', '0.020',
  '0.023', '0.027', '0.031', '0.035',
  '0.035', '0.035', '0.035', '0.036',
  '0.037', '0.038', '0.039', '0.040',
  '0.041', '0.042', '0.043', '0.045',
  '0.047', '0.049', '0.051', '0.053',
  '0.055', '0.057', '0.059', '0.061',
  '0.064', '0.067', '0.070'
]]
```

I tried like this.

```
var lastData=[]
for (i in arrays) {
// I thought that if array still includes 0 data inside, than make it cumulative
   if (arrays[i].indexOf("0.000") !== -1) {
       console.log(i, ' is cumulative'
       lastData = arrays[i].map((elem, index) =>
                  arrays[i].slice(0, index + 1)
                           .reduce((a, b) => 
                            (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)).toFixed(3)))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.map()` and a custom function *isCumulative* to determine if each array is increasing continuously.

In this example, we'd use `Array.every()` to ensure every number is increasing:

```js
arrays= [[
  '0.029', '0.029', '0.030', '0.030', '0.031', '0.031',
  '0.032', '0.032', '0.033', '0.034', '0.034', '0.034',
  '0.039', '0.039', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.002', '0.003', '0.003', '0.004', '0.004',
  '0.005', '0.006', '0.006', '0.007', '0.007', '0.008',
  '0.011', '0.012', '0.012', '0.013', '0.014', '0.014',
  '0.015', '0.015', '0.016', '0.017'
],
[
  '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002',
  '0.003', '0.003', '0.003', '0.003',
  '0.003', '0.004', '0.004', '0.004',
  '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.001', '0.001', '0.001',
  '0.001', '0.001', '0.001', '0.002',
  '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002',
  '0.003', '0.003', '0.003'
],
// Cumulative array
[
  '0.002', '0.004', '0.006', '0.008',
  '0.011', '0.014', '0.017', '0.020',
  '0.023', '0.027', '0.031', '0.035',
  '0.035', '0.035', '0.035', '0.036',
  '0.037', '0.038', '0.039', '0.040',
  '0.041', '0.042', '0.043', '0.045',
  '0.047', '0.049', '0.051', '0.053',
  '0.055', '0.057', '0.059', '0.061',
  '0.064', '0.067', '0.070'
],
[
   '0.000','0.001','0.002','0.003' 
],
[
   '0.000','0.002','0.001','0.003' 
]
]

// Return true if elements in the array are monotonically increasing _or_ equal to previous element.
function isCumulative(arr) {
    return arr.every(greaterThanOrEqual);
}

function greaterThanOrEqual(el, idx, arr) {
    const prevElement = arr[idx-1];
    return !idx || +el >= +prevElement;
}

const result = arrays.map(isCumulative);
console.log('Result:', result)
```

For a single array:

```js
function greaterThanOrEqual(el, idx, arr) {
    const prevElement = arr[idx-1];
    return !idx || +el >= +prevElement;
}

const singleArray = ['0.01', '0.02', '0.03'];
const result = singleArray.every(greaterThanOrEqual);
console.log('singleArray result:', result)
```

Comment: Thanx ur answer but we cannot change sequence of datas, sorting changes indexes, it gives wrong result. Just I need to check `is it cumulative?`

Comment: where does it sort your arrays? what are you talking about? The literal title of the question is how to `check` and they're correct

Comment: Hey @TheBombSquad, I've updated the answer, hope that clarifies things a little!

Comment: @apsisxcoder if u wanna make your array cumulative if it's not, it'd be something like `if(!isCumulative(myArr)){ myArr.sort((a,b)=>a-b) }`

Comment: @TerryLennox, so how can we check single array in this function? I tried directly `const result = singleArray.map(greaterThanOrEqual)`, it gives me `[
  true, true, true,  true,  true, true, true, true,  true,
  true, true, true,  false, true, true, true, true,  true,
  true]`

Comment: You'd use singleArray.every(greaterThanOrEqual). That should work...